# How to concatenate multiple Pandas series' of type string into a single Pandas series while inserting hyphens and spaces?

Tags: python, pandas

**Problem:**

I have some raw data with issues relating to the date and time information-- things like not having a colon to separate hours from minutes, as well as containing `2400`. I'm converting the individual columns to strings and modifying as required with the purpose of creating a single column of strings that can be parsed. I have about 20 data sets with about 35,000 rows each.

**Sample Data:**

```
a = ["2000"] * 100000
b = ["176"] * 100000
c = ["00:15","00:30","00:45","01:00"] * 25000   
d = {"year":a,"DOY":b,"time":c}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df.head()

    DOY time    year
0   176 00:15   2000
1   176 00:30   2000
2   176 00:45   2000
3   176 01:00   2000
4   176 00:15   2000
```

**My slow solution:**

I have created the following line to complete the task but it is quite **slow**:

```
df["date"] = [df["year"][i]+"-"+df["DOY"][i]+" "+df["time"][i] for i in range(0,len(df),1)]

df.head()

    DOY time    year    date
0   176 00:15   2000    2000-176 00:15
1   176 00:30   2000    2000-176 00:30
2   176 00:45   2000    2000-176 00:45
3   176 01:00   2000    2000-176 01:00
4   176 00:15   2000    2000-176 00:15
```

**Question:**

What is the **fastest** way to concatenate the `year`, `DOY`, and `time` columns *while inserting the appropriate hyphens and spaces* for the purpose of parsing into datetime format? Or is this the wrong approach altogether?

As always, thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be much faster than looping over the `df`.

```
df['Date'] = df['year'].map(str) + "-" + df['DOY'].map(str) + " " +  df['time'].map(str)
```

`.map()` maps the input values against a corresponding value in the passed in type, dict, Series, or function. You can find more info in [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas.Series.map).

[More Info](https://python-course.eu/lambda.php)

Comment: That is much faster. Perhaps you could add a few lines explaining the `map()` function.

Comment: The docs are little sparse so here is a link that may help the next person: https://www.python-course.eu/lambda.php

Comment: Let me add that to the answer for the sake of completeness.